# Single Correct MCQ involving the motion of fragments after an explosion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, momentum, conservation-laws

A shell moving through the air is split into two fragments of mass m1 and m2 by its explosion which adds on energy E to the fragments. The magnitude of relative velocity between the two fragments after explosion is:

1. $\sqrt{\frac{2E(m_1+m_2)}{(m_1m_2)}}$
2. $\sqrt{2E}\frac{(m_1+m_2)}{(m_1m_2)}$
3. $\sqrt{2E}\left[\frac{\sqrt{m_1}+ \sqrt{m_2}}{\sqrt{m_1m_2}}\right]$
4. $0$

My progress so far:

- Shell exploded, fragments gained energy, so they can't stay stuck together. Therefore, option 4 i.e. $v_{rel}=0$ , is wrong.
- Option 2 is dimensionally wrong.
- Option 1 & option 3 differ in only numerator, by: $\sqrt{m_1+m_2} \;\; vs.\;\; (\sqrt{m_1} + \sqrt{m_2})$
- Tried $F_{ext} = 0, \ \ \Delta E = 0$, but couldn't isolate the variables for further solving as it is.
- I tried clever observation/guessing. If I take $m_1=m_2=m$ , then the relevant options (1, 3) got reduced to $\sqrt{4E/m} \;\; vs. \;\; 2\sqrt{2E/m}$.
- <strike>I will add further progress after making this assumption after i read the notifications for this question.</strike>

---

My Solution after taking the assumption above mentioned *(I am not asking for review, just am telling my progress, or work done by me so u dont have to repeat this)* :

$$F_{ext}=0 \Rightarrow p_i = p_f\;\;\; \& \;\;\; v_{cm, i} = v_{cm,f}$$
$$\Rightarrow 2mu = m(v_1+v_2) \;\;\; (\because m_1=m_2)$$
$$or, \;\;\; 4u^2 = (v_1+v_2)^2 \;\;\; (\text{dividing by $m$, then squaring}) \;\;\; \ldots(i)$$

---

$$\Delta E = 0 \Rightarrow K_i + E = K_f$$
$$(\times 4) \Rightarrow 4mu^2 + 4E = 2m(v_1^2+v_2^2)$$
$$or, \;\;\; 4E = m (v_1-v_2)^2 = m(v_{rel}^2) \;\;\; (\text{from $i$, and rearranging})$$
$$or, \;\;\; |v_{rel}| = \sqrt{4E/m}$$
$$\text{which is Option 1 (confirmed answer).}$$

---

So, I think the problem remains in isolating the variables....

Comment: Have you tried using the energy an momentum conservation laws?

Comment: yup, but no go... am retrying with some clever modifications to see if they work

Comment: Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: @emilio-pisanty should i add my pre work in post or as comment? and at the moment i dont have a good quality camera, so will writing the work be good? (i will still try to capture and post my work, but just clarifying in advance)!

Comment: If you want to add material, do so as an edit to the post rather than as a comment. If you want to add equations or other mathematics, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). However, please read the guidance in my previous comment carefully -- if you're just going to post your work and ask us to verify it, it will likely remain off-topic.

Comment: This is not a numerical problem. The title is misleading.

Comment: @ja72 can u please suggest one?

Comment: writing in TeX is really time consuming, more than 1 hour just flew by since I started writing :surprised:

Comment: @AdamLatosiński yes the ~~modification~~ narrowing down to special case (which i mentioned 5 hr ago) helped

Comment: @user8395964 "Multiple choice problem involving the motion of fragments after an explosion".

Comment: @qmechanic The newtonian mechanics tag says "For more general discussion of energy, momentum conservation etc., use classical-mechanics" thats why i changed the tag. Can u please bring to notice what i am missing? (no pun or offence intended!)